# Showing that a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that 
>   $$ f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} &  (x,y) ≠ (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$$
>   is bounded.

I thought about splitting it up into different cases like $x<y$ but it turned out to be too many and I could not cover all of them.
As a hint I got the idea to use the arithmetic geometric inequality.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What does it mean that it is "limited",and what do you mean splitting it up into different cases like ***x***

Comment: Does “is limited” mean “has a limit” and if so, at which point? (presumably $(0,0)$).

Comment: by limited i mean there is an constant C that for all |f(x,y)|<C and by splitting it up i meant to just look at specific combinations of x and y pairs so that i can assume things like for 1<x<y its like xy^2/(x^2+y^4) is less than y*y^2/y^4 which is equal to 1/y and this i limited by 1

Comment: Ah, the english word for that is *bounded.*

Comment: i am sorry for my bad english by limited i meant limited by a constant C

Comment: No need to apologize; just trying to understand the question.

Comment: I cleaned up the text. Next time make an effort to use proper LaTeX formatting.

Comment: thanks i just logged in today but i guess its common sense to use LaTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insight here is that the fraction is of the form $\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}$, with $a=x$ and $b=y^2$.
\begin{align*}
    (x-y^2)^2 &\geq 0 \\
\implies x^2 - 2xy^2 + y^4 &\geq 0 \\
\implies x^2 + y^4 &\geq 2xy^2 \\
\implies\frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^4} &\leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

You can also apply the arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality with $a = x^2$ and $b=y^4$.  Then
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{ab} &\leq \frac{1}{2}(a + b) \\
    \implies xy^2 &\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^4) \\
    \implies \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} &\leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you very much thats just beautiful its kinda 
embarrassing that i couldnt come up with any real solution an you just solved it without any hesitation thank you anyways

Comment: @MarcelHarrer: you're welcome.  The arithmetic mean-geometric mean identity will still work.

Comment: i still cant see how i could use it but i got more time to think about it so it isnt that bad

Answer (score 0):

It can be estimated as $-1\leq\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq1:$

LHS: $-1\leq\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} \Rightarrow y^4+xy^2+x^2\geq0 \Rightarrow D=x^2-4x^2<0$ and $y=0 \Rightarrow x^2\geq0.$

RHS: $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}\leq1 \Rightarrow y^4-xy^2+x^2\geq0 \Rightarrow D=x^2-4x^2<0$ and $y=0 \Rightarrow x^2\geq0.$